# Как добавить в словарь данные парсинга?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium

Задавал вопрос вчера по поводу сайта dns-shop.ru
Подсказал один хороший человек использовать Selenium.
Теперь возникла другая проблема. Я выдернул всё, что я хотел - имена товаров, стоимость и ссылки на них.
Не могу понять как мне всё это дело запихать в словарь. Чтобы название было ключом, а стоимость и ссылка значением.
Я создал словарь d={}, и при прохождении цикла for, записываются в список. Но проблема в том, что запись идет сначала всех имен товаров, потом всей стоимости, потом ссылок. А мне надо, чтобы было имя, стоимость, ссылка и т.д.
Возможно мне надо использовать вложенные циклы, но получается фигня какая-то, выводит сначала имя, потом все цены, ссылки, потом опять одно имя, все цены со страницы и ссылки и т.д.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html

page_num = 1
url = 'https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a8a01d16404e77/smartfony/?p=%s&i=1&mode=list&brand=brand-apple' % page_num

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
content = driver.page_source

tree = html.fromstring(content)

last_page = tree.xpath('//span[@class=" item edge"]')[0].attrib.get('data-page-number')
last_page = int(last_page)
d={}

while page_num <= last_page:
    url = 'https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a8a01d16404e77/smartfony/?p=%s&i=1&mode=list&brand=brand-apple' % page_num

    driver.get(url)

    name = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
    price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('price_g')
    link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='title']/a")

    print('Страница: ', page_num)

    for i in name:
        i = i.text
        print(i)
        d.append(i)

    for i in price:
        i = i.text
        print(i)
        d.append(i)

    for i in link:
        i = i.get_attribute("href")
        print(i)
        d.append(i)

    page_num += 1
print (d)
driver.close()
```

я сделал сейчас так:

```
for i in name:
    i = i.text
    for j in price:
        j = j.text
        for k in link:
            k = k.get_attribute("href")
            d[i] = [j ,k]
```

вроде бы так как я хотел, но цена и ссылка не соответствуют товару.

Переделал d из словаря в список. Сработало только для первой "троицы", потом пошли одни ссылки и цена в хаотичном порядке. Не понимаю почему так

```
    for i in name:
    i = i.text
    d.append(i)
    for j in price:
        j = j.text
        d.append(j)
        for k in link:
            k = k.get_attribute("href")
            d.append(k)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но проблема в том, что запись идет сначала всех имен товаров, потом
> всей стоимости, потом ссылок. А мне надо, чтобы было имя, стоимость,
> ссылка и т.д.

Предлагаю решение на месте (другим, лучшим, вариантом будет обработка каждого продукта по отдельности с вытаскиванием из него его свойств, вместо запросов всех свойств всех продуктов и склейки их).

Вместо:

```
name = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('price_g')
link = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='title']/a")

print('Страница: ', page_num)

for i in name:
    i = i.text
    print(i)
    d.append(i)

for i in price:
    i = i.text
    print(i)
    d.append(i)

for i in link:
    i = i.get_attribute("href")
    print(i)
    d.append(i)
```

Сделайте так:

```
names = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h3')
prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('price_g')
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='title']/a")

print('Страница: ', page_num)

for name, price, link in zip(names, prices, links):
    name = name.text
    price = price.text
    link = link.get_attribute("href")
    
    print(name, price, link)
    # d.append((name, price, link))
```

---

**PS.**

Выражение `d.append(...` не будет работать если `d` -- словарь (`d={}`). Либо вы после присваиваете список в `d` либо у вас там ошибка

Comment: но можно же d сделать списком и в него добавлять по очереди. А потом из списка сделать к примеру файл csv

Comment: @AlexanderGninenko, можно. Но вместо `d = {}` используйте например `items = []`, ну и `items.append((name, price, link))`. А там и в csv можно запихнуть это добро :)

Comment: Да. Так и сделал) Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Я лишь добавлю несколько хороших советов к вашему коду! Всё это не очень смотриться в комментарии)))

1.

```
content = driver.page_source
tree = html.fromstring(content)
```

можно писать сразу:

```
tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
```

тогда у вас не будет лишней переменной `content`, в которой что-то будет храниться мёртвым грузом всё время работы скрипта)))) это что-то типо мини-оптимизации потребления ОЗУ вашим скриптом))

2.

```
last_page = tree.xpath('//span[@class=" item edge"]')[0].attrib.get('data-page-number')
```

Вы сначала находите элемент по Xpath, а затем ищете атрибут `attrib.get()`.

Хотя lxml умеет работать с контентом элемента, поэтому лучше:

```
last_page = tree.xpath('//span[@class=" item edge"]/@data-page-number')
```

Это вернёт цифру `6` (максимум страниц) в вашу переменную `last_page`

НО. Навигация по контенту не работает, если элемент вы ищете не `lxml`, а `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()`:

Если записать `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class=" item edge"]/@data-page-number')` вылетит `exception` что xpath не корректный. Нужно так:

```
last_page = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class=" item edge"]').get_attribute("data-page-number")
```

И ещё немного укоротить XPath убрав `span`, что-бы искать только по названию класса - `'//*[@class=" item edge"]/@data-page-number'`:

```
last_page = tree.xpath('//span[@class=" item edge"]')[0].attrib.get('data-page-number')
last_page = tree.xpath('//span[@class=" item edge"]/@data-page-number')
last_page = tree.xpath('//*[@class=" item edge"]/@data-page-number')
```